# Display loading images for multiple ajax requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net-ajax

I have a series of div in my  page, in which I append data returning from multiple ajax calls, that start after the click on a button. I want to display a loading gif image in each div until my data are returned, and than remove the gif and display the image. The strange thing is that when at first I click on the button it doesn't display anything, but after the first request get a response and the content is loaded in the specific div, the images are displayed in other div. 
These are the divs on my page

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="no-more-tables col-md-4" id="divCamere"></div>
        <div class="no-more-tables col-md-4" id="divOpzioniSoggiorno"></div>
        <div class="no-more-tables col-md-4" id="divOpzioniCamera"></div>
        <div class="no-more-tables col-md-4" id="divPromoCode"></div>
        <div class="no-more-tables col-md-4" id="divListino"></div>
        <div class="no-more-tables col-md-4" id="divOfferteSpeciali"></div>

    </div>
</div>
```

This is the code on my script where I append the images in the divs after the click of the button:

```
$(document).on('click', '#Button1', function (evt) {
evt.preventDefault();

$("#divCamere").empty();
$("#divOpzioniSoggiorno").empty();
$("#divOpzioniCamera").empty();
$("#divPromoCode").empty();
$("#divListino").empty();
$("#divOfferteSpeciali").empty();

$("#divCamere").append('<img src="imagesAjax/Loading_icon.gif" id="loadingCamere" class="loadingImage"/>');
$("#divOpzioniSoggiorno").append('<img src="imagesAjax/Loading_icon.gif" id="loadingOpzSoggiorno" class="loadingImage"/>');
$("#divOpzioniCamera").append('<img src="imagesAjax/Loading_icon.gif" id="loadingOpzCamera" class="loadingImage"/>');
$("#divPromoCode").append('<img src="imagesAjax/Loading_icon.gif" id="loadingPromoCode" class="loadingImage"/>');
$("#divListino").append('<img src="imagesAjax/Loading_icon.gif" id="loadingListino" class="loadingImage"/>');
$("#divOfferteSpeciali").append('<img src="imagesAjax/Loading_icon.gif" id="loadingOfferteSpeciali" class="loadingImage"/>');

$(".loadingImage").css('visibility', 'visible');
...
```

I can't understand while the loading gifs aren't displayed right after the click

Comment: Are your AJAX request synchronous? Also note that you can DRY that entire block of code up to just a couple of lines.

Comment: No, the requests are asynchronous. Thanks, I didn't notice that I can resume all the block in two rows, did you mean that I can do so? `$(.no-more-tables).empty; $(.no-more-tables).append('<img src="imagesAjax/Loading_icon.gif" class="loadingImage"/>');`?

Comment: That's it exactly. Although there doesn't seem to be any reason for the image not displaying. You could try pre-loading it

Comment: Are your images transparent ?

Comment: It's a classic rolling gif with the background transparent